# database in not updating online but work at localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a database table it is working fine when i check on localhost but its not working when i upload on server and it doesn't show any error also.the script is running fine

Comment: place your script and database information

Answer (score 0):

What error message are you getting?  Make sure errors are enabled.  This will help pinpoint the problem.  Likely it's just that your address isn't "localhost" anymore or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the table has a prefix or not.
Most likely you are missing the correct name of the table, or the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem occyed when database structure is different in server and local host or error in connection to database.

try out below code at db  connection function

```
if(!mysql_connect($host,$user,$password))
{
echo mysql_error();
}
if(!mysql_connect_db($databse_name))
{
echo mysql_error();
}
```

try out code for testing your error where you execute query

```
if(!mysql_query($query))
{
echo mysql_error();
}
```